# Hyperion issue when opening excel file

Tags: excel, hyperion

I've googled this everywhere - but can't seem to find a way of describing the issue that summarizes it perfectly.  Here it goes:

When I open up a file in Excel (with Hyperion open/active), you can't input data until you hit ESC or F2 to edit a cell.  If you start typing in a cell, it will pull up menu commands that are associated with the keys you typed.  You have to double click in a cell, hit ESC or F2 to edit a cell for the commands not to pop up.

I want to get rid of need to hit ESC or F2 and be able to edit a cell immediately.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this your own bqy file, or something you're opening in the browser with the Hyperion plugin?  Were you using Hyperion to open Excel with JOOLE?  if so, what's the code you used?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not exactly sure what a bqy file is, but after googling it, this is happening to all users in Hyperion.  Not using JOOLE.  Not sure of the code.  Sorry I'm not more technical.  This just happens when you have Hyperion active and open an Excel file.

Comment: bqy is a Brio Query File.  Hyperion is now owned by Oracle, but it used to be called Brio before it was Hyperion.  Typically, a developer will create a bqy file using a desktop application, it will be uploaded to a server, and then that file will be opened by users through their browser, with a plugin.  So I was trying to figure out if this was through the browser or the desktop application, and if it was the same file every time.